# Is there a faster way to copy lots of files?

Tags: uplink

I'm doing some of the "steal a database" missions and it is painfully slow copying individual files one by one.

Is there a way to copy all the files at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main way to speed up file copies is to **upgrade your gateway to be able to handle more bandwidth.** This will get each individual file on your machine faster. Beyond that, there's no ability to select multiple files and copy them over at once.

Comment: So no command line option I take it.

Comment: None that I know of. There are batch deletes (delete an entire folder), but not copy. More info: http://guide.modlink.net/section2.php#2-8